# Unconfirmed transaction / double spend warning

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, doublespend

I transferred some coins from my Electrum Wallet to my Coinbase Wallet, however the transaction got stuck as unconfirmed (possibly because of low fees).  It has been already 19 days since the transaction, the coins are still showing as unconfirmed in Electrum wallet and I can not use them as well.

I am also getting a double-spend warning on BlockCypher.  How can I push this transaction through without losing my coins?

Comment: and Coinbase is not showing this as an incoming/pending transaction.

Answer (score 0):

if the fee is not below 0.0001BTC/KB.    you can accelerate the transaction using viabtc accelerator. 
https://pool.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/

Comment: this is what's showing on the blockcypher for the fee: 0.00001347 BTC

Comment: copy the transaction id and head over to the link I gave you solve the captcha and summit the transaction id and wait for the out come